# Updating to the new MySQLi library

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to do a seat booking system, and i need to check via MySQL if the seat X is available. If there is a name assigned to it, print "Not Avalible", else if there is no name assigned to it, print "available!".

I successfully wrote a code that works but now i need to update it to the new MySQLi library. This is the code with the old MySQL library that works:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect(localhost, root, root);
mysql_select_db(V3); 
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$i=0;
$number = 1;
$letter = 'A';

while ($i<336){
 if($number > 14){
   $letter++;
   $number = 1;
 }
 $seat = $letter . $number;
 $result  = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = '$seat'");
   if( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
     if( $r['name'] == '' ){
     print 'Avalible';
   }else{
     print 'Not Avalible';
   }
   }
 $i++;
 $numero++;
}


?>
```

This is me trying to use the new MySQLi library:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "V3";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$i=0;
$number = 1;
$letter = 'A';

while ($i<336){
if($number > 14){
$letter++;
$number = 1;
}
$seat = $letter . $number;
$result  = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = '$seat'");
if( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
if( $r['name'] == '' ){
print 'Avalible';
}else{
print 'Not Avalible';
}
}
$i++;
$numero++;
}
```

And of course, it doesn't work. It prints nothing. Help?

Comment: **doesn't work** causes the sea to boil and the trees to catch fire?

Comment: Doesn't work is quite vague, could you provide more information (errors, warnings, ..)? Probably the fact that you are mixing `mysqli` with `mysql` is causing problems

Comment: don't you need to do "..seat = '".$seat."'

Comment: ^^ all mysql_* or ALL mysqli_* no mixing allowed

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and the other part of my comment: You have `mysqli()` and `mysql_query` (see the missing **i**?)

Comment: use `$conn->query` instead of `mysql_query` and `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: @Dagon unlike bourbon, scotch and beer

Comment: chips and dip borother

Comment: if you consider  2004-07-13 new.  http://www.quora.com/When-were-MySQLi-and-PDO-released.  Someone needs to scrub all the ancient php tutorials off the web